# Sifr3: Multiple fonts in one line

Tags: sifr

Is it possible to apply multiple fonts in one headline?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly build multiple Sifrs for this, eg.

```
<h1><span class='big'>Hello</span> <span class='medium'>world</span></h1>
```

Then Sifrize each span separately. I have done this, but realize it starts looking kind of clunky as they appear on the page. If this is the only headline, though, should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed multiple fonts in the same Flash movie, and use `span` elements with classes (or other selectors) to specify appropriate font families in the `sIFR.replace()` call.